# UITableView section headers disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` with this implementation of headers:

```
 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
    }
```

Other than that it's pretty much default.
When I scroll to the bottom of the table view, the headers of the table view disappear leaving blank space instead. If I start scrolling e.g. change offset even by 1 px I get the headers back. Any ideas why this situation occurs?

Comment: i think that happens because the table will reload the data once the table scrolls back to the top, and that happens every time. so maybe somewhere in your code you are changing some of the alignment of the table, or maybe your method that returns the title is taking longer to load as compared to the reload method of the UITableView. it is hard to see the real problem, as there is nothing much here to work with, maybe you can explain what you are exactly doing and/or show some codes so we can help. :)

Comment: it happens even if i drag to the bottom, so there is nothing about reloading data